# Laravel where to put a database function to include in all pages (routes)?

Tags: laravel

I have a laravel application which already have several routes, some controllers and some functions inside those controllers.

What I want to do is to fetch some data from database and want to use those data in all pages (routes).

```
function getNotifications() 
{
    $notifications = Notification::all();
    return $notifications;
}
```

I want to use **$notifications** in all pages (routes). Where should I put that function? I also want to follow DRY principle. So I put that function in Middleware and it works. But I saw suggestions middleware should not be used for that kind of purpose. I think helper function is not the way to go too.

Any idea?

I hope you can understand my problem. I wrote all other features first and notification feature at the last. Notification need to show in all pages.

Comment: you want this for views, or you need these notifications in other places as well?

Comment: @lagbox I think I need it for views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is a Laravel view composer

```
class UserComposer
{
    public function compose(View $view)
    {
        $user = Auth::user();

        $view->with([
            'user' => $user,
            'notifications' => $user ? $user->unreadNotifications : null,
        ]);
    }
}
```

In the boot method in ComposerServiceProvider

```
View::composer(
    '*',
    \App\Http\ViewComposers\UserComposer::class
);
```

Now you can access $notifications in all your views

More help from docs
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/views#view-composers

Comment: This is a valid, but OP wants to use `$notifications` inside Controllers as well. Never mind just read OPs comment.

Answer (score 1):

I hope using middleware in routes is the best options. First create a middleware

```
php artisan make:middleware GetNotification
```

It will create GetNotification.php inside app/http/middleware and inside handle method,

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $notifications = Notification::all();
    Session::put('notifications', $notifications);

    return $next($request);
}
```

and now you have to register it in app/http/kernel.php inside $routeMiddleware like

```
'getnotification'=> \App\Http\Middleware\GetNotification::class,
```

and now you can use in routes that is web.php , place all your route inside

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['getnotification']], function () {
....................
.......all routes here
});
```

and you can access session in any view or blade file by

```
@if(Session::has('notifications'))
echo {{ Session::get('notifications')}}
@endif
```

hope it helps.